# Nested ng-repeat will not loop if first field is undefined?

Tags: html, angularjs

I am attempting to do a nested loop to access the tutor information and the logs the students made for the tutor in my HTML

HTML:

```
<table ng-if="vm.log.length !== 0 && vm.checked === 1" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Tutor First Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr  ng-repeat="log in vm.logs ">
            <td>{{logs.tutorFirst}}</td>
            <td>
                <table> 
                    <tr ng-repeat="Student in StudentLogs track by $index">
                     <td> {{Student.log}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JSON:

```
[
    "Tutorfirst" :"tutor"
],
[
   "Tutorfirst" :"tutor"
       "Student" :{
          "log"  : "INFO"
      }
],
```

The JSON might not be correct but my question is,
Will the ng-repeat initiate if the first object does not have the field i'm trying to loop?

Comment: What error do you receive? BTW, you seem to have a typo. What is correct - `vm.logs` or `vm.log`?

Comment: Also, Your Student object has the same key twice, you're using tutoFirst in the code, but Tutorfirst in the JSON, etc. etc. Be consistent. And use the singular form for variables referencing an object, and the plural form for variables referencing an array.

Comment: What is `StudentLogs`?  That doesn't correspond to anything else you've provided in your question.

Comment: @31piy What I am asking is if the if I'm trying to loop thru several objects but part of the object does not exist on the first object, will the loop initialize or will it do nothing. Currently my second nested loop does nothing

Comment: We can't answer without seeing what `vm.logs`  contains (sample data, not the whole thing).  If that's what you're showing in your JSON, then the first loop will run, the second loop will do nothing *on the elements* that do not contain `studentlogs` (although currently there's a mistake - where is `studentlogs` getting set?

Comment: **Answer:** The first loop works.  Your second loop does nothing because `studentLogs` is not *ever* set (based on your JSON).  Change the `ng-repeat` to `ng-repeat="s in Student track by $index">` (or similar), because `Student` IS set, but `studentLog` is NOT

Comment: @cale_b Thank you very much that was the problem